# be careful to do something

Tags: to-infinitive

If you are careful **to do something**, does it mean you do it carefully, or you are careful in order to do it? What is the function of the infinitival phrase?

Comment: You take care to ensure that it is done.

Comment: Do you mean "to V" in "be careful to V" indicates a purpose?

Comment: "Be careful to do X" means "make sure that you don't forget do X". "Be careful doing X" means "do it in a careful way."